# WindowChromeでClearTypeを適用したい

Tags: wpf, font

WindowChromeを使用するとClearTypeが無効になってしまいます。
これを通常ウィンドウと同様にClearTypeを適用したいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか。

### 環境

- .NET Framework 4.8
- Windows 10

### 試したこと

`RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"` を設定してみたのですが、この場合、範囲内に収まるテキストには効果あるのですが、見切れるようなテキストにはClearTypeが効きません。
以下、そのテストコードになります。

```xml
<Window x:Class="ClearTypeTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClearTypeTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <StackPanel Width="64">
            <TextBlock Text="Sample" />
            <TextBlock Text="Long Long Text Sample" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

結果の拡大画像です。下段のテキストにClearTypeが効いていません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ちょっと説明が合っていない感じですが、もしかしたらこれが何か影響しているのかも？ [RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint 添付プロパティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint?view=netframework-4.8) 試しに個々の`TextBlock`に`RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"`を入れてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: それぞれのTextBlockに直接 `RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"` を設定してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。ちなみにテストコードではWindowコントロールに設定しています。

Comment: 駄目でしたか。残念ですね。